# running ant file on a remote server from a web page

Tags: php, batch-file, ant

I have a requirement in my project. My manager wants me to run an ant build file which is in my local machine(SYS A) from his computer(SYS B) using web page. I have installed Tomcat server and it is up and running in SYS A. I created a batch file for running the ant build file in SYS A. I tried using PHP to run my local batch file from a machine in my network it didn't work. Can anyone please help me with this?

following is the code I used in PHP. I tried running the batch file from SYS B, but its not working. Please help me.

**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = file_get_contents("C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0_srv-mobile\webapps\ANT-TEST\printfile.bat");
$output = exec($file);
print_r($output);
} else {
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

**

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't enough information for us to help really. I suggest you explain exactly what you've tried and what goes wrong.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: sorry for the vague post. please check it and let me know if you can help me.

Comment: Wouldn't installing Jenkins on the build machine make a lot more sense? Possible to invoke builds using the Jenkins API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Jenkins (ex Hudson) like [Mark O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256618/mark-oconnor). You can create as many jobs (tasks) as required. It is possible to have a mobile app to manage Jenkins jobs as well - not only website but a mobile app as well. http://jenkins-ci.mobi/